# How to resolve Blocked a frame with origin(SecurityError) from kibana iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, kibana

I installed opendistro using docker and deployed that in Nginx. Used "iframe" to display the dashboards from kibana in React js.
This is my iframe component in react js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Iframe component{
   handleOnclick=(e)=>{
    let ifrm=e.target; 
    console.log(ifrm);
    let document=ifrm.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML; //to get the iframe content
   }
   render(){
     return(
       <div >
          <iframe onClick={(e)=>{this.handleOnclick(e)}} className="iframe" 
             src="https://example.com/api/v1/auth/authinfo"/>
       </div>
    )}
   }
```

this is what i am getting in my console:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="https://example.com/api/v1/auth/authinfo">
#document
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
       {"user":"User [name=admin, roles=[admin],requestedTenant=admin_tenant]","user_name":"admin","user_requested_tenant":"admin_tenant","remote_address":"172.29.0.4:57896","backend_roles":["admin"],"custom_attribute_names":["attr.jwt.roles","attr.jwt.sub","attr.jwt.saml_nif","attr.jwt.nbf","attr.jwt.exp","attr.jwt.saml_si"],"roles":["all_access","own_index"],"tenants":{"admin_tenant":true,"test_tenant":true,"admin_user":true,"global_tenant":true},"principal":null,"peer_certificates":"0","sso_logout_url":null}
    </pre>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

whenever I am trying to fetch that user information from the iframe document it is giving me an error.

```
Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

can anyone help me to fetch that iframe content.

Comment: By reading a few articles I come to know that iframe won't work for different protocols and domain names that mean my custom_react_app is working on "http://anlaysis2.gromor.in:3000" and my kibana is on "https://analysis2.gromor.in" which mean both are running on different "protocols" and "ports".